# Magento: How to set 404 error on advanced search page?

Tags: magento

I removed *catalogsearch_advanced_index* section from catalogsearch.xml. Now I get empty page *catalogsearch/advanced/index/*

How to set 404 error for this page then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the controller. Without the xml layout, the controller will still render an empty page. In order to get Magento to not respond to that url, you have to remove the controller. Or maybe you could use a redirect.